# Opencart 2.3.0.2 How to create carousel for products

Tags: php, mysql, opencart

I need to create a carousel for some category products, how do I proceed?

Comment: you can create module based on implementation of 'featured' module

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can solve your issue:

1. Admin > System > Design > Banners -> Edit or Insert Banner
2. (*`See Banner Page`*) -> Insert Image (*`repeat for more`*) by clicking "Add banner"
3. Upload images in banner
4. Admin -> Extension -> Modules -> Carousel (*`module`*)
5. Add module -> Select banner in 1st column (*`make banner uploaded`*) -> Set Size in 2nd Column,
6. Layout selection - > Save

For displaying banner images, the `Slideshow module` can also be used.